# delete statement in mysql where query ok 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing some problems in mysql in following statement which is

```
select *
from actors a 
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from movies z where z.actorid = a.actorid);
```

this statement is working properly but the following statement is not working and which is

```
delete from actors
where NOT EXISTS(select 1 from movies z where z.actorid = actorid );
```

in the terminal it is showing that QUERY OK,0 rows affected

Answer (score 0):

You need the table alias for the `actorid` column in the subquery:

```
delete from actors
where not exists (select 1 from movies z where z.actorid = actors.actorid );
```

Otherwise, the `actorid` resolves to `z.actorid`.

Comment: He says that _"QUERY OK"_, but _"0 rows affected"_, does that mean that `movies` table has a column named `actorid`?If no, should not that produce an error?

Comment: @andrewnagyeb . . . `z.actorid` suggests that `movies` has that column.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff for your interest in my problem and for giving the solution I have tried the solution which you gave me and it was working I am very Happy to be in between a programmers environment

Answer (score 0):

The query `select 1 from movies z where z.actorid = actorid`, standing alone, spews a result set with a `1` for every row of your `movies` table. Why?  `where z.actorid = actorid` is the same as `where z.actorid = z.actorid`, which in turn is the same as `where 1 = 1`, a no-op filter clause accepting all rows.

`NOT EXISTS(that result set)` is always false as long as you have any rows in `movies`.

So your `delete` clause looks like `delete from actors where not exists (select 1)`: The `where` clause always comes up false. Hence the `delete` query operates on zero rows.

How do you troubleshooot this kind of stuff?

1. Run your subqueries standalone and eyeball the result sets.
2. substitute SELECT for UPDATE or DELETE and eyeball the result sets.

Comment: Thank you very much O Jones